# serial port forwarding/virtualisation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, port-forwarding, serial

I have a python script(UBUNTU) reading and writing info from local serial port. It works fine!

What if instead of using the local serial port, I want to use another machine serial port, remotely?

how would you implement this:

- between 2 ubuntu machines?
- between 1 ubuntu and one windows machine?

It's not so simple to explain so i made this little diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> between 2 ubuntu machines

[Serial Over IP](http://freshmeat.net/projects/serialoverip/)

> between 1 ubuntu and one windows machine

Ubuntu [ser2net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/), Windows [HW VSP3](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

the most generic way I can think of is by reading the local serial console, and redirecting it to a netcat port. then on the receiving side, a netcat listener, or python itself, can pick up the datastream